# How to Import Reconfigured apk File from Amazon Appstore into Eclipse for Signing

Tags: eclipse, amazon-appstore

Amazon App Store (appstore) - Marketplace requires you to upload unsigned apk files. They then reconfigure and add their own coding.  They then ask you to download that reconfigured file, sign it, then re-upload it to their site.

I'm having a heck of a time trying to import that reconfigured file into Eclipse for signing.  Do I use the IMPORT option?  If so, what specific steps?  Or do I use the Terminal to sign?

I tried importing the new file the same way I imported my original project (using Wizard: Android>Android Project...) but that won't work for the new file.

Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.

PS  I found a great site that helps with eclipse and installing apks.  But it didn't answer this question.
http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=3279

Answer (score 0):

The ADT plugins for Eclipse can't import an APK to sign it, they can only export a signed (or unsigned) APK. But these instructions from the Android Developers site should help you get on your way: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the .apk file back into Eclipse, but can sign it from command line. In fact, Eclipse invokes this same procedure behind the scenes when it signs your binary.

In the samples below, replace the AppName with your application's name. The first step (to generate the keystore file) you will do only once when you setup your project, and the other 2 steps -- every time you need to sign the app. I hope that answers your question.

```
:: Generate a keystore file
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin"
keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore AppName.keystore -alias AppName -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

:: Sign the .apk file
cd "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin"
jarsigner.exe" -keystore AppName.keystore AppName.apk AppName

:: Zip align the .apk file and copy it to the install folder
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\android\android-sdk\tools"
zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 AppName.apk install\AppName.apk
```